# NACHOS on eclipse exception in thread "main"

Tags: java, nachos

I am getting  the following error when running nachos in eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at nachos.machine.Lib.assertTrue(Lib.java:75)
    at nachos.machine.Machine.main(Machine.java:24)
```

The above two methods are as follows:

nachos.machine.Lib.assertTrue:

```
public static void assertTrue(boolean expression) {
    if (!expression)
        throw new AssertionFailureError();
    }
```

nachos.machine.Machine.main:

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("nachos 5.0j initializing...");
    Lib.assertTrue(Machine.args == null);//This is the call after which error is thrown
    Machine.args = args;

    processArgs();

    Config.load(configFileName);

    // get the current directory (.)
    baseDirectory = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
    // get the nachos directory (./nachos)
    nachosDirectory = new File(baseDirectory, "nachos");

    String testDirectoryName =
        Config.getString("FileSystem.testDirectory");

    // get the test directory
    if (testDirectoryName != null) {
        testDirectory = new File(testDirectoryName);
    }
    else {
        // use ../test
        testDirectory = new File(baseDirectory.getParentFile(), "test");
    }

    securityManager = new NachosSecurityManager(testDirectory);
    privilege = securityManager.getPrivilege();

    privilege.machine = new MachinePrivilege();

    TCB.givePrivilege(privilege);
    privilege.stats = stats;

    securityManager.enable();
    createDevices();
    checkUserClasses();

    autoGrader = (AutoGrader) Lib.constructObject(autoGraderClassName);

    new TCB().start(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { autoGrader.start(privilege); }
    });
    }
```

Comment: `Unresolved compilation problem` means there was a compilation error in the source code.  You need to show the compilation error messages.

Comment: Did you mean `AssertionFailureError` or `AssertionFailedError` ? If the former - where and how is it defined ?

Comment: Yes, AssertionFailureError is defined as follows:
 
class AssertionFailureError extends Error {
    AssertionFailureError() {
 super();
    }

    AssertionFailureError(String message) {
 super(message);
    }
}
/*On compiling I am getting the following error:
The serializable class AssertionFailureError does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long.*/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error come up for me when I was trying to run nachos through eclipse. What I did was to look at Lib.java and scroll down to the function with an eclipse error on it. For me it was `checkDerivation`. There should be an eclipse error on the parameters `<?>`, if you look at the auto fix eclipse gives you and pick the project wide fix nachos should run after that.